# Fazer aplicativo armazenar mensagens em servidor

Tags: php

Eu quero que meu app android cujo o objetivo e a comunicação entre a escola e os pais, envio de notas, avisos, armazene uma copia de todas as mensagens tipo backup,e o dono do app ter acesso as copias ?

Tem como fazer isso com php ?

Comment: Claramente que sim, basta escrever o conteúdo desejado em arquivo ou gerenciar no próprio banco de dados.

Comment: Ai que está eu quero entender como devo faze, como implantar a comunicação do app pra enviar o backup pro servidor ?

Comment: Que App? É android? PHP é back-end e não front-end, tua pergunta não faz muito sentido da maneira que esta, tem como explicar isso ae direito?

Comment: Eu sei que php e back end e uma linguagem de servidor, por isso quero usa-la para que meu app android envia-se uma copia de todas as mensagens

Comment: O que pede é amplo demais pois envolve muitas coisas. Para te dar um norte, com php vc cria uma API que vai rodar no servidor onde estará também o banco de dados. Com o app, feito em java (android) ou objective-c (ios), vc cria o app que vai ler e interagir com os dados provindos da API. 
Claro, pode criar o app mobile com javascript somente, ou swift (xcode).. enfim, o app nativo no mobile vc não faz em php.. é outro universo. Existem diversos meios para criar esses apps. Mas o básico é JAVA para Android e Objective-C ou Swift para iOS. Percebe como é amplo o que pede?

Comment: sim, cara eu pensei em php pois tenho um pouco de habito com ele e considero uma linguagem boa quando se trata de segurança, entendi o que devo fazer vlw pela ajuda

Comment: Seu app é híbrido (html5, CSS, JS) ou nativo?

Comment: Ele foi feito no android studio totalmente em java, não e hibrido